# syntax error, unexpected ''<div id="errors">'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Tags: php, xampp, syntax-error

```
<?php if(isset($error)) {$echo '<div id="errors">'.$error.'</div>'; }?>
```

I don't know what is the error but because of it I cannot procced in my project
please somebody help me with it.

Comment: syntax error, check is anything missing in your coding ... such as  } or ) etc...

Comment: its `echo`, not `$echo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?php if(isset($error)) {echo ("<div id='errors'>$error</div>");}?>
```